# Font proxima_novalight is rendered as Times New Roman

Tags: css, fonts

I have a problem rendering a font. In one part of the site every thing works fine. I have in my css

```
font-family: proxima_novalight;
```

and if I go in the `Computed` style section of chrome, I see this in the rendered fonts section at the bottom:

```
hp4c7LFzMk-VFtNvUrXnVg==—15 glyphs
```

But, I have no idea what this cryptic characters means.

In other part of my site, I style have the same css style (no override, I checked)

```
font-family: proxima_novalight;
```

But if I go in the `Computed` section and then in the rendered fonts, I see:

```
Times New Roman—15 glyphs
```

Does anyone has any idea of what is going on ?

When I check or uncheck the CSS property, the rendering goes back to `Arial` default font. So it really act as if the css property force a Times New Roman rendering, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Need, at the very least to the @font-face declaration.

Comment: I don't have more code to show, I just put the css property and the style according in the html. I just notice know that the browser is trying to download the font, but from the wrong location on the server, but I don't know where to specify the location of fonts

Comment: Ok thank you @Paulie_D, it was indeed in the \@font-face declaration

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the `@font-face` declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
    src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Light-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Light-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Light-webfont.svg#proxima_novalight') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```